# Implement single sign on functionality in rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

Currently I am trying to implement Single Sign On (SSO) in rails 4.

Consider the I have one main app `demo.com` and three sub-domain apps (basically each one is separate rails application) `sub0.demo.com, sub1.demo.com, sub2.demo.com`

Now I have to login all of the application through the `demo.com` (let consider I have same users on all of the applications)

For this I looked into the [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10402777/share-session-cookies-between-subdomains-in-rails) and tried to implement it.

So I have a following questions

- Is it the good way for doing this?
- As per the given link, I am trying to implement the given functionality for this I have did following steps

  1. As I am working on local, set the domain in `/etc/hosts/` file

  127.0.0.1       demo.com

  127.0.0.1       sub0.demo.com

  127.0.0.1       sub1.demo.com

  2. Also made changes in the following files from the `sub1.demo.com`

**session_store.rb**

```
Rails.application.config.session_store :cookie_store, :key => '_tourlyapp_session', :domain => "demo.com"
```

But it is not working even though I have set the same key for all the application.

Is there any thing I am missing.

Comment: There is zillion gems that could be used for this; I don’t think SO’s purpose is to suggest different kind of things you could try to do.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried doorkeeper gem , it is for what you are looking https://github.com/doorkeeper-gem/doorkeeper I have also found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11351484/single-logon-with-different-applications-approach-ruby-on-rails) post related to it